# How do I get the proper characters to appear instead of "?"s in my jSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, encoding, utf-8, jboss

I’m using JBoss 7.1.3.Final on Amazon Linux (Java 6).  We have set the system property, “org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING” to “UTF-8,” which I validate because I can call

```
System.err.println("encoding:" + System.getProperty("org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING"));
```

and the result is

```
encoding:UTF-8
```

In our database (MySQL 5.5.37), we have a value stored,

```
Detectives and “Evidence”
```

Notice the curly quotes.  This can be seen fine in our MySQL command line tool.  However, on our JSP when we have

```
<input type="hidden" class="data-name" value=“${myMap.key.name}" />
```

What is output to the browser is

```
<input type="hidden" class="data-name" value="Detectives and ?Evidence?" />
```

How do we get the curly quotes to appear instead of the “?”s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it's a problem connected with a characters set of a particular jsp; try to include

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

into the jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Even after changing charset if issue still persist,  check if you are using Stored procedure to return the value.  If yes then ensure you are using 'text'  data type for respective value.